# Reading a process memory

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

I'm trying to read the process memory  of a console program using ReadProcessMemory() API function.

**Updated Code:**

```
    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, "Read Memory Window");
    DWORD ProcessId;
    ProcessId = GetProcessId(hWnd);
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &ProcessId);
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ,FALSE, ProcessId);

    SIZE_T NumberOfBytesRead;
    CHAR Buffer[128] = {0};
    dwAddr = 0x0012FD6C; //address of array to get
    BOOL sucess = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, &dwAddr, &Buffer, 128, &NumberOfBytesRead);
```

I get null and garbage values as i run the program along with program to read the array.

Comment: Where's the code to open the hProcess? Are you sure it's succeeding?
Are you sure that address contains valid data in the target process?

Comment: yes, I get a valid process id from window handle

Comment: NumberOfBytesRead returns a value of 128.

Comment: The process ID is not what you need for ReadProcessMemory. You need to open the process' ID's handle which you often cannot do without the SeDebugPrivilege, which is granted only to administrators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your using a fixed address, that is generally a very bad idea, even more so now that windows vista and windows 7 use [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), making it unsafe for even fixed based modules(even without ASLR its unsafe, because the image can reallocated for various reasons).

also, that address looks very dodgy, how did you derive that address? and is it adjusted correctly as a virtual address and not a relative address?

finally and most importantly, you shouldn't be passing the address and buffer as you do, it should be passed like so:

```
BOOL sucess = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)dwAddr, &Buffer[0], 128, &NumberOfBytesRead);
```

or

```
BOOL sucess = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)dwAddr, Buffer, 128, &NumberOfBytesRead);
```

Comment: Using the LPVOID to cast the DWORD dwAddr helps, actually when I was trying to read the data from process, I tried to change the array to integer type, int Buffer[128]. so there I made a mistake, In fourth level of ReadProcessMemory() the number of bytes to read should be 128*4 = 512 Bytes.